# what is the command line equivalent of ctrl f5 of visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I created a simple uwp app with microsoft Visual Studio

To build the project

```
MSBuild -t:build -p:Platform=x64
```

I tried to run the project with

```
MSBuild -t:run -p:Platform=x64
```

But it's like this:
[image]

However, in the Visual Studio GUI, I press ctrl F5

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe run the exe from the release folder instead of the debug folder? your images and text aren't doing a very good job of telling us why you think something is wrong, or what that thing is.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a non-debug build configuration when envoking MSBuild.

`MSBuild projectOrSolutionFile /property:Configuration=Release`

you can configure your build configurations in VS (Project > Configuration Manager) or in the project file.

More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669626/how-to-build-some-project-configurations-with-msbuild